# Android 12 delete images file not working

Tags: android, image, android-camera, android-contentresolver, android-12

For android 12 i cannot remove image file created by app. Method File.delete() is ignored, i don't get error but file still exist after it.

Image file is created by press "Add photo button", after pressing at first this method is invoked:

```
 private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    try {
        File photoFile = createImageFile();

        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.i("ERROR",e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Create image file method:

```
private File createImageFile() {
    String imageFileName = String.format(new Locale("pl"), PHOTO_FILE_FORMAT, currentMonth.getMonth(), currentMonth.getYear());
    File storageDir = new File(ShiftCalendarApplication.PHOTO_DIRECTORY);

    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
        if(!storageDir.mkdirs())
            return null;
    }

    return new File(ShiftCalendarApplication.PHOTO_DIRECTORY, imageFileName + FILE_EXTENSION);
}
```

Photo directory:

```
   public static final String PHOTO_DIRECTORY = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath() + "/My App/" + "Zdjecia/";
```

File is delete by pressing another button which invoke this method is user select "yes" when is asked about deletion.

```
    private void deleteSelectedImage() {
    if (photos.get(monthsFromToday) != null) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PhotoOfScheduleActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Usuń zdjęcie")
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setMessage("Czy na pewno usunąć?")
                .setPositiveButton("Usuń", (dialog, which) -> {
                    File file = new File(paths.get(monthsFromToday));

                    Log.d("SAVED_IMAGE", "(BEFORE)FILE EXIST: " + file.exists());
                    file.delete();
                    Log.d("SAVED_IMAGE", "(AFTER)FILE EXIST: " + file.exists()); // FILE STILL EXIST HERE

                    reloadDrawables();
                    adapter = new SchedulePhotosPagerAdapter();
                    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(monthsFromToday);
                })
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setNegativeButton("Anuluj", null)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Reload Drawabled method which store paths for photos:

```
    private void reloadDrawables() {
    File directory = new File(ShiftCalendarApplication.PHOTO_DIRECTORY);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    photos = new SparseArray<>();
    paths = new SparseArray<>();
    int year = currentMonth.getYear();
    int month = currentMonth.getMonth();
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();

    if (directory.listFiles() != null) {
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(FILE_EXTENSION)) {
                try {
                    Photo photo = new Photo(removeExtension(file.getName()), file.getPath());
                    String[] date = photo.getPhotoName().split("-");
                    int pYear = Integer.parseInt(date[1]);
                    int pMonth = Integer.parseInt(date[0]);
                    int key = monthsFromToday;
                    key += (pYear - year) * 12;
                    key += pMonth - month;
                    paths.put(key, file.getPath());
                    photos.put(key, photo);
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (adapter != null) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

File.delete() not working for for android > 29 in this case

Comment: Pretty unclear. If you can create files with the File class then you can delete them with the File class too. Please rewrite your post as your scenario is unclear.

Comment: That is the case, I can create file with File class but I can't delete the file with it. Buy I will rewrite it later

Comment: `if (!storageDir.exists()) {
       if(! storageDir.mkdirs()) return null;
    }`

Comment: How this code can resolve my problem ? If I can create file and has access to it through path that mean directory exist right ? 
Genrally right now whole cycle looks like that:

1. Create file by new File(directory)
2. Create photo through Intent
3. Save photo in file
4. refresh screen
5. retrieve photo from directory and display it.
6. if I click delete button, file should be removed by file.delete() <--- this is not working in android 12
7. page is refreshed and info for empty sreeen without photo text info is displayed.

Comment: Instead of your comment you should have posted code to create the file and after that the code where you try to delete the file. Remove all other code. Show what you do instead of talking about it.

Comment: Here you go. :)

Comment: You have not adopted the mkdir code.

Comment: And you dont need that camera intent as you created already a file with createImageFile();. Of 0 bytes. But it is still a file.

Comment: Your delete code makes no sense. What does it have to do with the file you created?

Comment: Where should I put mkdir code ? Before file.delete() ? And why I need it only for android 12 and why I need it at all if I use it when file is created ?

Comment: You should adapt your existing mkdir code in the way i proposed.

Comment: even if it makes no sense, delete.file() is rather simple method which should delete a file and debug after it should return false right ?

Comment: I added reloadDrawable() method code. file paths are saved there in map.

Comment: Your delete code makes no sense. You should use `photoFile.delete();`

Comment: If it makes no sense why it works for android < 29 Sometimes I do not create new photo but use already existing one,  did you read my last comment question ? I asked why file.delete() not working. It's independed method.

Answer (score 0):

Staring on API 29, there a are a lot of [non-SDK interfaces that have stopped working](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/non-sdk-q#new-blocked). java.io.file is one of the affected ones so it's no longer functional.

This is how I solved the issue:

```
import android.content.ContentResolver
import java.io.File

//'file' is the instance of your java.io.File
//'app' is your app context.

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
    file.delete()
}else{
    val resolver = app.contentResolver
    resolver.delete(file.toUri(), null, null)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from Android 11 an higher
to delete file from external or internal Storage.
**public or private path.**
use **MediaStore** to **Delete Files**.

this Answer for delete any Media File.(With a slight modification)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75640130/14035342

you can use **same code Answer**.
only Change this method in the answer link to like this

```
private Uri get_Files_media_uri() {
        //MediaStore.Audio.Media.. or MediaStore.Video.Media... is same value value uri but title permission dialog deference as Audio or video
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
            return MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
        else
            return MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }
```