# Delete files in Android 11

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to delete files (photos, videos, audio) with the consent of the user. But when I try to bring up a window for the user agreement, I get an error. For some reason my `Uri` variable doesn't fit

My code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30) {
            val collection: ArrayList<Uri> = ArrayList()

            for (i in 0 until Params.dataListPath.size) {
                collection.add(Params.dataListPath[i].file.path.toUri())
                Log.d(TAG, "onShowDialogConfirmDelete: " + collection[i].path)
            }

            val  pendingIntent = MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(requireActivity().contentResolver, collection).intentSender

            startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent, 100, null, 0, 0, 0, null)
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: All requested items must be referenced by specific ID
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:172)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:142)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:732)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.call(ContentResolver.java:2433)
        at android.provider.MediaStore.createRequest(MediaStore.java:834)
        at android.provider.MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(MediaStore.java:997)
        at com.test.cleanerapp.duplicate_files.view.fragment.DuplicateFindFragment.onShowDialogConfirmDelete(DuplicateFindFragment.kt:119)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Delete files in Android 11 and higher** and less

The solution for **new** and **old** Version by **MediaStore**

stepes:

1. Append specefice _Id media.
2. create *request Delete Permission* and send it.
3. after press Allows Button in permission dialog. you can listener
   result from onActivityResult override method .

**how to call method:**
I am use a MediaStoreM model to add the _id and path media as list

```
String path="/storage/emulated/0/Download/Video/nameVideoFile.mp4";
                    //or
                    //path="/storage/2332-4883/EveryThing/nameAudioFile.mp3";
                    int id =get_Id_MediaByPath(mContext,path);
                    List<MediaStoreM> list=new ArrayList<>();
                    list.add(new MediaStoreM(id,path));
                    deleteMediaStore(mContext, list);





//1
 public void deleteMediaStore(Context mContext, List<MediaStoreM> list) {
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {//SDK>=30
                List<Uri> listRequest = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    if (new File(list.get(i).getPath()).exists()) {
                        Uri uriRequest = ContentUris.withAppendedId(get_Files_media_uri(), list.get(i).getId());
                        listRequest.add(uriRequest);
                    }
                }
                requestDeletePermission(mContext, listRequest);
            } else {//SDK<=29
                for (MediaStoreM m : list) {
                    File file = new File(m.getPath());
                    if (file.exists())
                        file.delete();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("zakaria_mediaD","   mediaDelete error:\n"+e.getMessage());
        }

    }

//2
private Uri get_Files_media_uri() {
        //MediaStore.Audio.Media.. or MediaStore.Video.Media... is same value but title of permission dialog deference. as Audio or video you can do
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
            return MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
        else
            return MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }


private int get_Id_MediaByPath(Context mContext,String path) {
        Cursor cursor=mContext.getContentResolver().query(get_Files_media_uri(),new String[]{"_id"}
                ,"_data=?",new String[]{path},null);
        if (cursor.getCount()>0){
         return cursor.getInt(0);
        }else return 0;
    }


//3 requestDeletePermissio
private static final int REQUEST_PERM_DELETE = 8;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
    public void requestDeletePermission(Context context, List<Uri> uri_list) {
        try {
            PendingIntent editPendingIntent = MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(context.getContentResolver(), uri_list);
            startIntentSenderForResult(editPendingIntent.getIntentSender(), REQUEST_PERM_DELETE, null, 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            Log.i("zakaria_mediaD","   requestDeletePermission error:\n"+e.getMessage());

        }
    }



//5 process done
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_PERM_DELETE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Toast.makeText(yy_MusicApp.this, "Deleted successfully! Refreshing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(yy_MusicApp.this, "Failed to delete!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

**create Model Class "MediaStoreM.java"**

```
    public class MediaStoreM {
    
    private int id;
    private String path;
    public MediaStoreM(int id, String path){
        this.id=id;
        this.path=path;
        //..
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
}
```